# Need help on data types and class implementation

Tags: xcode, ios, macos, quartz-graphics, nsimage

I need to implement a class which will be used for same image operations. Class should store image data and have methods to do:

- cropping (this will return object of same class)
- binarization of image (making it black-white with specific threshold)
- some other stuff based on direct pixel manipulation (so I need access to raw data)

I'd need some advices on data types to use. What to use for storing image data? NSImage, CGImage, CIImage? Which of those can help me binarize image? With which could I do pixel manipulation?

I was thinking in saving image data in 2-D array and then implement my binarization method and others. But how do I get 2D array of pixels and how to make of that image later?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you already know how to read pixels from the image? Which image format do you have in mind?

Comment: I'm working with jpg, but i'd like it to be independent of format.

Comment: In that case, you should rely on 3rd party libraries like OpenCV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are allowed to use 3rd party libraries, take a look at [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298941/leak-in-opencv-nsimage-to-iplimage-converter-procedure

Comment: http://opencv-cocoa.googlecode.com/svn-history/r5/trunk/src/highgui/window_cocoa.mm